# In Python, how to keep track of variable in the response of a REST API for changes?

Tags: python

I have a REST API, which returns a JSON response. I need to keep track of one of the fields of the response, and listen for any changes in the value of this field. If the value reaches a certain threshold, I need to perform some task (say print an alert message). How can I accomplish this? Right now, I have a daemon which runs periodically, making an HTTP request and obtaining the value. What is the correct approach to do this, if I want to perform the action the moment the variable reaches the threshold? 
This is what I currently have -

```
import daemon, time
from daemon import runner
NUMBER_OF_MINUTES = 10

def doSomething():
    print "Yay, we got there"

def getSomeData():
    url = "www.somewebsite.com/getdata?id=somevalue&name=someothervalue"
    response = requests.get(url)
    json_data = response.json()
    myField = json_data['somefield']
    if myField > threshold:
        doSomething()

def run()
    while True:
        getSomeData()
        time.sleep(60*NUMBER_OF_MINUTES)

if __name__ == '__main__':
run()
```

Comment: You should show how you tried to solve it, this website is more about solving existing issues rather than designing solutions.

Comment: as @WNG said - please update your question with your attempt and code and we will try and help

Comment: Edited. Sorry for being a complete noob

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control of the API?  If so, add a websocket endpoint that your frontend app can connect to.  Your API can then let your frontend app know whenever the value changes, through whatever data structure is appropriate.

If you don't have control of the API, your current polling solution is about as good as it gets.